# Gimp Unicode in Text Editor doesn't work

Tags: linux, fonts, unicode, gimp

Linux Mint 18.3 (= Ubuntu Xenial), Gimp 2.8.16

In Gimp Text Editor (something you can show when you're entering text using Text Tool) you are meant to be able to go Ctrl-Shift-U + Unicode code... and the symbol in question is meant to be shown.

This appears to be dependent on using the right kind of font (presumably one covering the Unicode code pages in question).

It never, ever works for me. Going Ctrl-Shift-U does not print "u", just nothing at all. Entering the hex or decimal code for the code point just prints those numbers + letters as text.

Answer (score 2):

Ah... just found the/an answer to this, but propose not to delete question.

In GIMP Text Editor dialog, if I right-click, I find a dialog giving the chance to choose "Input Method".  This *was* set to "System (X Input Method)"... I changed this to "Simple"... and the Unicode functionality started to work.

I recently installed an application called [IBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) which does in fact provide a method of alternate inputs to apps. It may therefore be that everyone else's system will by default be "Simple".

Comment: Still doesn't work for me